# Different results for the same equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Why does the chart of $xy+yz+xz=-1$, a one sheeted hyperbolid, is different from the chart of $z = -\frac{1}{x+y} - \frac{xy}{x+y}$?

Aren't they both the same equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different because the latter is defined only when $x+y\not=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Well: $$z = -\frac{1}{x+y} - \frac{xy}{x+y} \iff xz+yz = -1-xy \iff xy+xz+yz = -1,$$provided that $x+y \neq 0$ so that you can make the division.